# VB.NET increase sql value by an integer variable

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, connection-string

whats the best way to increase the slected sql value by a vb.net integer variable

should i first get the value of the cell i want to increase, or there is a way to do the increment using a single command?

one thing i am not sure of is how can i save the value to a vb.net integer variable

here is what i have so far

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Suppbackorder FROM products WHERE catalogid=@catalogid"
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@catalogid", someid))
```

Comment: Well you can add it once you get the selected value from the database, any reason you would want that to be added in the select query itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all obvious which value you want to increase by a specified amount, here is something that may help guide you (excuse my rusty VB):

```
Dim myMagicValue as Int = 10

sqlcmd.CommandText = "UPDATE products SET mySpecialColumn = mySpecialColumn + @magicValue WHERE catalogid=@catalogid"
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@catalogid", someid))
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@magicValue", myMagicValue))
```

As you can see your `WHERE` clause remains the same, all we do is change the `SELECT` to an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

By using queries

```
SELECT ISNULL(Suppbackorder,0)+1 FROM products WHERE catalogid=@catalogid
```

Comment: can i replace the +1 with +@somenumber ?